# How can I boot from a USB flash drive with Alienware Aurora R7?

Tags: boot, bios, usb-boot

How can I boot from a USB flash drive with Alienware Aurora R7?

I have enabled the USB boot support in the BIOS, but I don't see USB in the boot menu.

---

USB boot support is enabled in the BIOS:

[image]

No USB option in the boot menu:

[image]

[image]

The USB ports are activated:

[image]

Switching from legacy to UEFI boot didn't help:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The USB flash drive seems recognized as its light indicator is flashing when the computer starts. The USB flash drive was  formatted to be bootable with  [rufus](https://rufus.ie/) and has an image on it. It shows up in Windows Explorer when logged into Microsoft Windows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m assuming the USB has been formatted to be bootable and has an image on it? Does it show up in explorer when logged into Windows?

Comment: @DrZoo correct, using https://rufus.ie

Comment: And it shows up in explorer?

Comment: @DrZoo I'll let you know in around one hour when I try

Comment: @DrZoo It shows up in Windows Explorer when logged into Microsoft Windows. I have added a screenshot of it at the end of the question's details. I'll create another bootable USB key on some basic Ubuntu to make sure the issue isn't specific to this USB key. I'll try on Monday or Tuesday and will keep you posted. Other ideas welcome in the meantime!

Comment: Hmm interesting. I’d try making another one as you suggested. You seem to have everything correct.

Comment: @DrZoo It seems that the USB flash drive was formatted for UEFI (screenshot from another computer that isn't  Alienware Aurora R7: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUFrl.jpg), so it's strange it didn't work when I switched the BIOS to UEFI. I'll try disabling the legacy option ROMs. Plan B is re-creating the USB flash drive with the legacy mode as explained on the screenshot.

Comment: @DrZoo Turns out the partition scheme is incorrect, and in the BIOS installed on Aurora  does not give any error message about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I should have used the MBR partition scheme (and not GPT) when creating the bootable USB flash drive with https://rufus.ie. Here are the proper settings:

[image]

After doing so, I see USB in the boot options:

[image]

I didn't expect the partition scheme was incorrect as on one of my other computers (non Aurora), if the partition scheme is incorrect, I can still see USB flash disk as a boot option:

[image]

and I get a clear error message:

[image]